# Transformation of saliency map on orignal image

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, heatmap, transformation

I am working on saliency image prediction and using this https://github.com/marcellacornia/sam GitHub repository. The model gives me a saliency image as output and I want to make some changes like transforming the saliency image into a heatmap on the original image, I try the following code  but the results are not good enough. I attached my results and targeted results images for your consideration. The black and white image is saliency and the image with red heatmap is my result I am trying to make my results much similar to the green heatmap transformation. can someone suggest to me what I am doing wrong or how I can achieve a result clearly like a green heatmap? I will be thankful for suggestions to improve my results.

[image: my results]

[image: saliency image]
[image: expected results]
[source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylLFK.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image1 = cv2.imread("Source.jpeg")
image2=cv2.imread("Saliency.png")
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(image2, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
weight = cv2.addWeighted(image1,0.5, heatmap ,0.8 ,0.3)
cv2.imshow("Result",weight )
```

Answer (score 1):

The colormap choice is what determines the color result. You are using the ["hot"](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#gga9a805d8262bcbe273f16be9ea2055a65a5d4a709cda1130bfa3cc4b4c5ae8f82a)  colormap.

replace

```
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(image2, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
```

with

```
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(image2, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
```

and you should obtain the result you're looking for!